# Entity Type not defined when Customer Field Code is run

Tags: javascript, dynamics-crm

I've been working on this code. When I run it and some fields don't exist, the error of `Entity Type not defined` pops up. I tried If statements but it still isn't working. I've read it may have something to do with the currency but I can't seem to figure out what. I'm a beginner and most of this isn't my code. Help! Thanks.

```js
function customerSelected() {
    var customerID = Xrm.Page.getAttribute("customerid").getValue();
    var custID = customerID[0].id.substr(1, 36);

    var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
    req.open("GET", Xrm.Page.context.getClientUrl() + "/api/data/v8.2/accounts?$select=_defaultpricelevelid_value,paymenttermscode,shippingmethodcode&$filter=accountid eq " + custID + "&$orderby=name asc", true);
    req.setRequestHeader("OData-MaxVersion", "4.0");
    req.setRequestHeader("OData-Version", "4.0");
    req.setRequestHeader("Accept", "application/json");
    req.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=utf-8");
    req.setRequestHeader("Prefer", "odata.include-annotations=\"*\"");
    req.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (this.readyState === 4) {
            req.onreadystatechange = null;
            if (this.status === 200) {
                var results = JSON.parse(this.response);
                for (var i = 0; i < results.value.length; i++) {
                    var _defaultpricelevelid_value = results.value[i]["_defaultpricelevelid_value"];
                    var _defaultpricelevelid_value_formatted = results.value[i]["_defaultpricelevelid_value@OData.Community.Display.V1.FormattedValue"];
                    var _defaultpricelevelid_value_lookuplogicalname = results.value[i]["_defaultpricelevelid_value@Microsoft.Dynamics.CRM.lookuplogicalname"];
                    var paymenttermscode = results.value[i]["paymenttermscode"];
                    var paymenttermscode_formatted = results.value[i]["paymenttermscode@OData.Community.Display.V1.FormattedValue"];
                    var shippingmethodcode = results.value[i]["shippingmethodcode"];
                    var shippingmethodcode_formatted = results.value[i]["shippingmethodcode@OData.Community.Display.V1.FormattedValue"];

                    var _defaultpricelevelid_lookupVal = new Array();                    
                    _defaultpricelevelid_lookupVal[0] = new Object();
                    _defaultpricelevelid_lookupVal[0].id = _defaultpricelevelid_value;
                    _defaultpricelevelid_lookupVal[0].name = _defaultpricelevelid_value_formatted;
                    _defaultpricelevelid_lookupVal[0].entityType = _defaultpricelevelid_value_lookuplogicalname;


                    if ("pricelevelid" != null)
                    {
                        Xrm.Page.getAttribute("pricelevelid").setValue(_defaultpricelevelid_lookupVal);
                    } 


                    if ("paymenttermscode" != null)
                    {
                        Xrm.Page.getAttribute("paymenttermscode").setValue(_defaultpricelevelid_lookupVal);
                    }

                    if ("shippingmethodcode" != null)
                    {
                        Xrm.Page.getAttribute("shippingmethodcode").setValue(_defaultpricelevelid_lookupVal);
                    }
                }
            } else {
                Xrm.Utility.alertDialog(this.statusText);
            }
        }
    };
    req.send();
};
```

Comment: 1) This 'results.value[i]["paymenttermscode"]' can be null, this '"pricelevelid"' can not be null. 2) The data model should be consistent and fields should be present. But their value might be empty. Is this the problem? 3) There are propably more problems in the code, but which line of code throw error?

Comment: It doesn't show up as a script error. In my VSCode everything looks good. why can't the pricelevelid be null? Some of the Potential Customers don't have some of these fields. So I am trying to make it so that we can at least get the fields they do have.

Comment: 1) If it has quotes, it is a constant value, it is what you see, it is "pricelevelid". It is not null.  As well as number, like 27, is not null. But variable named pricelevelid can be null.
3) Try step thru the code in F12 tool to find the corrupted line.

Comment: the f12 debugger didn't show me anything. I'm confused as to what you are saying. about it. Also I made these edits to the if statements.if (_defaultpricelevelid_value_formatted != null)if (paymenttermscode_formatted != null)if (shippingmethodcode_formatted != null)

Answer (score 1):

Your query will always return exactly one record, so it does not make sense to use a loop to iterate the results.

Condition `("pricelevelid" != null)` will always be `true`. It probably should be `(_defaultpricelevelid_value != null)`. The same goes for the lines below it.

Your code is assigning `_defaultpricelevelid_lookupVal` to three separate attributes, which cannot be correct. Apparently this object is supposed to represent a lookup ID value referencing entity `pricelevel`. Therefore it only makes sense to assign it to attribute `pricelevelid`. `paymenttermscode` and `shippingmethodcode` are option set attributes and apparently need to be filled with the values of the equally named variables.

Replace the `for` loop with this code:

```
if (results.value[0]._defaultpricelevelid_value != null) {
    var priceLevelId = [{
        id = results.value[0]._defaultpricelevelid_value,
        name = results.value[0]["_defaultpricelevelid_value@OData.Community.Display.V1.FormattedValue"],
        entityType = "pricelevel"
    }];

    Xrm.Page.getAttribute("pricelevelid").setValue(priceLevelId);
}

if (results.value[0].paymenttermscode != null) {
    Xrm.Page.getAttribute("paymenttermscode").setValue(results.value[0].paymenttermscode);
}

if (results.value[0].shippingmethodcode != null) {
    Xrm.Page.getAttribute("shippingmethodcode").setValue(results.value[0].shippingmethodcode);
}
```